# Introducir en una lista un número concreto de variables(objetos) en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código:

```
    numeroJugadores = 6

    key = []
    jugador = []
    for i in range(numeroJugadores):
        key.append(random.randint(0, 30))
    for i in range(numeroJugadores):
        jugador.append(asignarCochesAJugadores(key[i])) 
        jugador[i] = Jugador(jugador[i])
        print(jugador[i].name)
    print(jugador)
    print(jugador[2].name)

    jugador1 =jugador[0]
    jugador2 =jugador[1]
    jugador3 =jugador[2]
    jugador4 =jugador[3]
    jugador5 =jugador[4]
    jugador6 =jugador[5]

    jugadores = [jugador1, jugador2, jugador3, jugador4, jugador5, jugador6]

    while wh <= 10:
        AsignarTurnos()

        if jugador1.turno > 0:
            jugador1.turno -= 1
```

El código está incompleto pero sirve para ilustrar lo que necesito.
Como véis he tenido que igualar `jugador1 =jugador[0]` y lo primero que busco es sacar directamente `jugador1`y el resto de objetos sin tener que hacer esa igualdad, para meterlos en la lista de objetos `jugadores`. Mi primer problema es ese, optimizar el código. Y el problema gordo es cómo hacer para que dependiendo de `numeroJugadores`, el resto de código se acomode a esa circunstancia, es decir, cómo hacer, por ejemplo, que si `numeroJugadores` es 120, la lista `jugadores` tenga 120 registros `jugador1, jugador 2,.....jugador120` sin olvidar que cada jugador es un objeto de la `clase Jugador`. E imaginaros tambien los `if jugador1.turno > 0:` tener que escribirlos 120 veces, mención aparte que al depender de `numeroJugadores` y siendo este a través de un `input` todavía no implementado, nunca sabré cuantos `if` tengo que poner. Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: No termino de entenderlo, ¿Qué diferencia hay entre la lista `jugador` y la lista `jugadores`? Ambas terminan con los mismo objetos... ¿Por qué no haces directamente `jugador[i] = Jugador(asignarCochesAJugadores(key[i]))`, porque `jugador.append(asignarCochesAJugadores(key[i]))` no tiene sentido si sobrescribes en la siguiente línea ese elemento. Por otro lado, puedes crear ambas listas en un mismo `for`.

Comment: `jugadores` es innecesaria ya que es redundante pero lo que sí necesito es llamar a los objetos por `jugador1.name` en lugar de `jugador[0].name`. Por eso creé `jugadores` que sería la que utilizaría en lugar de `jugador`. Precisamente ahí está el kit de la cuestión. Además, necesito saber como introducir variables consecutivas al vuelo en una lista, así que me servía para ensayar. No he conseguido ni lo uno ni lo otro. Con respecto al `for`  lo estuve mirando pero hay muchas líneas (que no se ven en el código de ejemplo) dependientes de `jugadorX` y no puedo meter en un for "mil líneas".

Comment: En el ``if jugador1.turno > 0:`` está toda la programación incluidas llamadas a diversas funciones. Si hay 4 jugadores debe haber 4 `if jugadorX.turno > 0:` pero si hay 200 jugadores tiene que haber 200 `if jugadorX.turno > 0:`. El problema está en que el número de `if` es variable y no puedo poner 500 `if` por si acaso los jugadores llegan a 500. Entonces, cómo puedo poner tantos `if` como jugadores haya?

Comment: En vez de poner 500 if basta con que iteres sobre la lista con los objetos `Jugador` con un `for in`.  por ejemplo, `for jugador in jugadores: if jugador.turno > 0:
            jugador.turno -= 1`

Comment: @FJSevilla Eso funciona y ya era una opción contemplada. El problema es que ya tengo muchas líneas escritas con funciones que interactúan con la clase `Jugador`. Por ejemplo, `jugador.nombreJugador = "JugadorAliado1"` ya no podría ponerlo porque al iterar, todos los jugadores se llamarían `"JugadorAliado1"` lo que me obligaría a iterar con una nueva lista y no sería la única. Además tendría que solucionar el problema de meter objetos consecutivos al vuelo en listas, que es una de las cuestiones que planteo en mi pregunta.

Comment: Toni creo que estás algo confundido con lo que es una "variable" en Python, que no es más que un nombre asociado a la referencia de un objeto en memoria. La variable `jugador` es exclusiva del `for`,  lo importante no es el nombre de la variable sino el objeto al que está asociado y varias variables pueden estar asociadas al mismo objeto incluso perteneciendo a distintos namespaces.

Comment: Si tus funciones reciben un objeto Jugador como argumento por ejemplo no hay problema alguno, si tus funciones usan variables globales jugador1, jugador500, etc te complicas sin razón además de ser muy mala práctica. ¿Podrías agregar algunas funciones de estas a ver si me aclaro en lo que intentas? No obstante, la única forma de evitar 500 if es usar un contenedor para los objetos e iterar...

Comment: Sí, me complico bastante pero por ahora estoy empezando con la poo y lo creas o no, `jugador1` y `jugador2` me hace la vida más fácil que `jugador[0]` y `jugador[1]` a la hora de hacer un seguimiento a las variables. Entonces, cómo hago, una vez que el objeto sea `jugador[0]` llamarlo por `jugador1.name` en lugar de `jugador[0].name`? Sé que al final lo voy a hacer como tú me has indicado pero necesito tener esta cuestión clara porque tengo la impresión de que lo voy a necesitar, si no ahora, sí más adelante.

Comment: Me refiero a cambiar `jugador[0]` por `jugador1` en un `for` (De uno en uno basta con hacer `jugador1 = jugador[0]`)

Comment: @FJSevilla Cómo puedo valorar tu respuesta? no veo las flechas en ninguno de tus comentarios.